# Getting the coordinates of the corners of the camera viewport in Mapbox Maps SDK for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapbox, mapbox-unity

I'm using Mapbox's Maps SDK for Unity and I'm having trouble getting the coordinates of the corners of the viewport. I'd like to be able to retrieve the latitude and longitude of the corners of the viewport each time I move the map [The attached image is the camera as it is centered on 42.3552435, -71.065219 which is Boston Commons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs375.jpg). I've been trying to get the values relating to the camera viewport by going through AbstractMap.cs which is attached to the MapBox map object which I've represented with the variable called 'map'. I believe that the values of the camera bounds are in the CameraBoundsTileProviderOptions.cs file, but I can't figure out how to get the values out of it. The documentation says that I have to use ExtentOptions to access the tile provider files, but that keeps giving me errors. Here's what I've been trying to do:

map.GetComponent().ExtentOptions.CameraBounsTileProviderOptions;

But it clearly isn't working and I don't know how to proceed. Does anyone have any ideas?